# Setting (permenant) environment variables in Ubuntu 10.0.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, environment-variables

I am running an application which requires setting environment variables to be set.

At the moment, the way I am achieving this is by exporting the EV at the command line, and then running the app from the command line.

I want to be able to run the app from my menu (it is already a menu item after I installed it).

How may I set the env var so that it is always available, so I can just run the app from the menu instead of from the CLI?

Comment: systemwide or per-user?

Answer (score 4):

Add the environment variable declarations to the file `.profile` in your home directory:

```
export NAME='value'
```

If there are single quotes in the value, replace them by `'\''` (there are other quoting mechanisms, this one is just the simplest to explain).

If you want to make the variables available to all users, add the declarations to `/etc/profile.d/my-app-environment.sh` (replace `my-app-environment` by a more descriptive name).

Comment: Did Lucid change `/etc/profile` from a file to a directory?

Comment: @Dennis: no, I meant `/etc/profile.d`, thanks for pointing it out. Since at least Ubuntu 8.04 and Debian lenny, `/etc/profile` sources `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`.

Comment: @Dennis, No - `/etc/profile` file loads what is in `/etc/profile.d` directory

Comment: @laurent: Yes, I know. It was a typo that threw me.